# A balancing pigeon puzzle

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

While designing a new logo for our company I had to solve a version of the geometric problem below. I have repackaged it here in the form of a puzzle that I hope others might enjoy!

[image: bird]

The pigeon drawn above in the Cartesian plane:

- consists of a straight line and 5 circle arcs
- is perfectly smooth along its perimeter except for the points labeled B,C,D and E on the graph
- tiles the plane

Assuming that the weight of the pigeon is distributed uniformly across its area, what are the co-ordinates of E such that it balances exactly on its foot?

Comment: Please include the source of this problem.  Have you done any work yourself?

Comment: @amWhy source is me, a problem I encountered when designing a logo. I know the geometric construction although I haven't yet worked out the exact answer to the question- my intention was more to post this an interesting challenge to others!

Comment: That's the kind of information you need to post **within your question**.

Comment: Knowing D is not sufficient, one also needs to know the curve/function from point C to D, which I take are each arcs of different circles, but there is not two points given for each of those two circles.  Not enough information to arrive at an answer.  You would need a point $F$ on the curve between C and D, such that CF is one arc of one circle, and DF is another arc of another circle.

Comment: Besides,  CE has is a line without area, and hence contributes nothing to the balance point if you consider weight distributed across the area of the bird. (Nor do you give coordinates for D).

Comment: @amWhy didn't realise context was mandatory - have added to the question! Thanks!

Comment: Please read my comments; you haven't enough information for anyone to be able to solve this.

Comment: @344 rep, you have no excuse to be ignorant of the fact taht context is required above and beyond problem statements.  To be sure you never claim ignorance again, please see: [How to ask a good question on math.se](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question?r=SearchResults&s=1|126.1762)

Comment: @amWhy thanks for the comments, I have read them. Respectfully, while some of your points are valid, I have thought carefully about how much information to provide in the question and believe it is possible to solve.

Comment: So you're posing this dishonestly as a question that you think you already have the answer to?  Hah!

Comment: First, if I were you wanting to sell an updated brand, I'd learn how to spell **PIGEON**.  Your repeated spelling of pidgeon revealed you made no typo.  Those are the kinds of details, like the ones I mention above, you need to pay attention to, if you want to be taken seriously.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118337/discussion-between-jmp-and-amwhy).

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer: I've just prepared the figure below, with the relevant geometric information. But finding the center of mass is too tedious for me...

[image]

Comment: Nice! But as you say, not technically an answer...